# Update a running sql script to update the last 2 years based on today's date

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I currently have a simple sql script (in Oracle) that updates based a date range >='01JUN13'. I'm trying to modify this script to automatically update based on the last two years based on today's date. So the next month, I need the last two years of data greater than or equal to July 2013. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at ADD_MONTHS function

Comment: This is a statement of your needs. What is your question? Have you tried to write such query?

Comment: Have no idea where to start. I've investigated ADD_MONTHS and saw several articles on including from "from dual" in my script for today's date. i have no idea how to write it tho.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question whether you want the date range to start from exactly two years ago, *to the day* , or from the start of the month.

Matching to the day:

```
select * from your_table
where date_col >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -24)
/
```

Matching to the first day of the month:

```
select * from your_table
where date_col >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -24)
/
```